# Android Billing Client causes memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, in-app-billing, leakcanary, play-billing-library

Simple `MainActivity` for a new project

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  BillingClient billingClient;
  PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {

    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    billingClient.endConnection();
}
```

in Gradle file:

```
  ....
  implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2'
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.5'
```

canary output (1 distinct leak):

````
┬───
│ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code
│
├─ android.os.MessageQueue instance
│    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue#mQuitting is false)
│    HandlerThread: "main"
│    ↓ MessageQueue.mMessages
│                   ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.os.Message instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 116109 bytes in 1346 objects
│    Message.what = 0
│    Message.when = 104320925 (14773 ms after heap dump)
│    Message.obj = null
│    Message.callback = instance @315501888 of com.android.billingclient.api.zzr
│    ↓ Message.callback
│              ~~~~~~~~
├─ com.android.billingclient.api.zzr instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 116024 bytes in 1344 objects
│    ↓ zzr.zzb
│          ~~~
├─ com.android.billingclient.api.zzag instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 115980 bytes in 1342 objects
│    ↓ zzag.zza
│           ~~~
├─ com.android.billingclient.api.zzah instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 115968 bytes in 1341 objects
│    ↓ zzah.zza
│           ~~~
├─ com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 115939 bytes in 1339 objects
│    zze instance of android.app.Application
│    zzf instance of android.app.Application
│    ↓ BillingClientImpl.zzd
│                        ~~~
├─ com.android.billingclient.api.zze instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 115881 bytes in 1338 objects
│    zza instance of android.app.Application
│    ↓ zze.zzb
│          ~~~
├─ com.android.billingclient.api.zzd instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 115865 bytes in 1337 objects
│    ↓ zzd.zzb
│          ~~~
├─ com.example.billingclientleak.MainActivity$1 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 115841 bytes in 1336 objects
│    Anonymous class implementing com.android.billingclient.api.
│    PurchasesUpdatedListener
│    this$0 instance of com.example.billingclientleak.MainActivity with
│    mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ MainActivity$1.this$0
│                     ~~~~~~
╰→ com.example.billingclientleak.MainActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.
​     billingclientleak.MainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and
​     Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 115829 bytes in 1335 objects
​     key = d55540b8-a7aa-4fa1-9eb1-ed14135a9a8d
​     watchDurationMillis = 5135
​     retainedDurationMillis = 133
​     mApplication instance of android.app.Application
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper, not
​     wrapping known Android context

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 27
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.5
App process name: com.example.billingclientleak
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=634,misses=23227,hitRate=2%]
RandomAccess[bytes=1191354,reads=23227,travel=6396792403,range=8851265,size=1152
9733]
Analysis duration: 7997 ms```
````

Comment: This is also logged as an issue in Google Billing Sample https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/185

Comment: @beginner Hi Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @MehranB Hi, sry, I didn't found the solution I got busy with some other project but I think you should check the given answer. it should work!, thx!